# choosing pivot for the quickselect using median implemented in java?

Tags: java, algorithm, median, median-of-medians, quickselect

I have found this code in github for `quickselect` algorithm otherwise known as `order-statistics`. This code works fine.

I do not understand `medianOf3` method, which is supposed to arrange the first, middle and last index in sorted order. but actually it does not when I ouput the array, after calling the `medianof3` method.
I could follow this method as to what it is doing except the last call of `swap(list, centerIndex, rightIndex - 1);`. can someone explain why this is called?

```
import java.util.Arrays;



/**
* This program determines the kth order statistic (the kth smallest number in a
* list) in O(n) time in the average case and O(n^2) time in the worst case. It
* achieves this through the Quickselect algorithm.
*
* @author John Kurlak <john@kurlak.com>
* @date 1/17/2013
*/
public class Quickselect {
   /**
* Runs the program with an example list.
*
* @param args The command-line arguments.
*/
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       int[] list = { 3, 5, 9, 10, 7, 40, 23, 45, 21, 2 };
       int k = 6;
       int median = medianOf3(list, 0, list.length-1);
       System.out.println(median);
       System.out.println("list is "+ Arrays.toString(list));
       Integer kthSmallest = quickselect(list, k);

       if (kthSmallest != null) {
           System.out.println("The kth smallest element in the list where k=" + k + " is " + kthSmallest + ".");
       } else {
           System.out.println("There is no kth smallest element in the list where k=" + k + ".");
       }
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));
   }

   /**
* Determines the kth order statistic for the given list.
*
* @param list The list.
* @param k The k value to use.
* @return The kth order statistic for the list.
*/
   public static Integer quickselect(int[] list, int k) {
       return quickselect(list, 0, list.length - 1, k);
   }

   /**
* Recursively determines the kth order statistic for the given list.
*
* @param list The list.
* @param leftIndex The left index of the current sublist.
* @param rightIndex The right index of the current sublist.
* @param k The k value to use.
* @return The kth order statistic for the list.
*/
   public static Integer quickselect(int[] list, int leftIndex, int rightIndex, int k) {
       // Edge case
       if (k < 1 || k > list.length) {
           return null;
       }

       // Base case
       if (leftIndex == rightIndex) {
           return list[leftIndex];
       }

       // Partition the sublist into two halves
       int pivotIndex = randomPartition(list, leftIndex, rightIndex);
       int sizeLeft = pivotIndex - leftIndex + 1;

       // Perform comparisons and recurse in binary search / quicksort fashion
       if (sizeLeft == k) {
           return list[pivotIndex];
       } else if (sizeLeft > k) {
           return quickselect(list, leftIndex, pivotIndex - 1, k);
       } else {
           return quickselect(list, pivotIndex + 1, rightIndex, k - sizeLeft);
       }
   }

   /**
* Randomly partitions a set about a pivot such that the values to the left
* of the pivot are less than or equal to the pivot and the values to the
* right of the pivot are greater than the pivot.
*
* @param list The list.
* @param leftIndex The left index of the current sublist.
* @param rightIndex The right index of the current sublist.
* @return The index of the pivot.
*/
   public static int randomPartition(int[] list, int leftIndex, int rightIndex) {
       int pivotIndex = medianOf3(list, leftIndex, rightIndex);
       int pivotValue = list[pivotIndex];
       int storeIndex = leftIndex;

       swap(list, pivotIndex, rightIndex);

       for (int i = leftIndex; i < rightIndex; i++) {
           if (list[i] <= pivotValue) {
               swap(list, storeIndex, i);
               storeIndex++;
           }
       }

       swap(list, rightIndex, storeIndex);

       return storeIndex;
   }

   /**
* Computes the median of the first value, middle value, and last value
* of a list. Also rearranges the first, middle, and last values of the
* list to be in sorted order.
*
* @param list The list.
* @param leftIndex The left index of the current sublist.
* @param rightIndex The right index of the current sublist.
* @return The index of the median value.
*/
   public static int medianOf3(int[] list, int leftIndex, int rightIndex) {
       int centerIndex = (leftIndex + rightIndex) / 2;

       if (list[leftIndex] > list[rightIndex]) {
           swap(list, leftIndex, centerIndex);
       }

       if (list[leftIndex] > list[rightIndex]) {
           swap(list, leftIndex, rightIndex);
       }

       if (list[centerIndex] > list[rightIndex]) {
           swap(list, centerIndex, rightIndex);
       }

       swap(list, centerIndex, rightIndex - 1);

       return rightIndex - 1;
   }

   /**
* Swaps two elements in a list.
*
* @param list The list.
* @param index1 The index of the first element to swap.
* @param index2 The index of the second element to swap.
*/
   public static void swap(int[] list, int index1, int index2) {
       int temp = list[index1];
       list[index1] = list[index2];
       list[index2] = temp;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I wrote the original code, but I did a poor job of making it readable.

Looking back at it, I don't think that line of code is necessary, but I think it is a small optimization.  If we remove the line of code and return `centerIndex`, it seems to work without any issues.

Unfortunately, the optimization it performs should be refactored out of `medianOf3()` and moved into `randomPartition()`.

Essentially, the optimization is that we want to "partially sort" our subarray as much as possible before partitioning it.  The reason being this: the more sorted our data is, the better our future partition choices will be, which means our run time will hopefully be closer to O(n) than O(n^2).  In the `randomPartition()` method, we move the pivot value to the far right of the subarray we're looking at.  This moves the far right value into the middle of the subarray.  This is not desired since the far right value is supposed to be a "larger value".  My code tries to prevent this by placing the pivot index right next to the rightmost index.  Then, when the pivot index is swapped with the rightmost index in `randomPartition()`, the "larger" rightmost value doesn't move into the middle of the subarray, but stays near the right.

Answer (score 0):

Function `medianOf3` is to define order of left median and right. Last statement

`swap(list, centerIndex, rightIndex - 1)`

is used to achieve following precondition of a sort:

> However,
>   instead of recursing into both sides, as in quicksort, quickselect
>   only recurses into one side – the side with the element it is
>   searching for. This reduces the average complexity from O(n log n) (in
>   quicksort) to O(n) (in quickselect).

And then algorithm continues with:

```
   for (int i = leftIndex; i < rightIndex; i++) {
       if (list[i] <= pivotValue) {
           swap(list, storeIndex, i);
           storeIndex++;
       }
   }
```

in order to

> that the values to the left  of the pivot are less than or equal to
>   the pivot and the values to the right of the pivot are greater than
>   the pivot.

Comment: I do not understhand how the precondition of a sort is acheived by this: `swap(list, centerIndex, rightIndex - 1)`. Ignoring this, will still recurse to one-side in quickselect.

Comment: At this moment center element is smaller than right element. So when you swap center element with (rightIndex - 1)th element you have ordered last two elements of that sublist. After that you are moving smaller element of center element(which is at position (rightIndex - 1) to the left and greater to the right. In the end you put center element to the right position :  swap(list, rightIndex, storeIndex)

Comment: what do you mean by "After that you are moving smaller elements of center elements at position...". I do not understand this point. would it be possible to illustrate within a simple array with 5 or less elements? that will be easy to follow. Thanks

Comment: Read my explanation. Then start code here: http://ideone.com/bJyB6s After each swap printed read carefully what I wrote and visualize.

Comment: Did visualization help you to understand? Do you need any additional clarifications?

Comment: I do not know why I am having difficulty to follow these. I tried to visualize, but I still do not see why the last swap is needed. even without that, it must be O(n).

Comment: if for example, you take this array:`[3, 5, 10, 9, 7, 1, 2]`, after the `medianof3` call, the arrays becomes `[2, 5, 10, 1, 7, 3, 9]`. why is this better than the array without last swap which is `[2, 5, 10, 3, 7, 1, 9]`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43790/discussion-between-user1988876-and-user987339)